# SVG displacement map filter

Tags: javascript, css, svg, filter, mapping

I was trying to implement fisheye-esque filter in my SVG and found this codepen:
 http://codepen.io/johanberonius/pen/RopjYW

It works perfectly fine except I want this effect to be slightly "harder", but I couldn't change displacement map since it generated in js.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        barrel = document.getElementById('filter-image'),
        width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height,
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            var dx = x - 128,
                dy = y - 128,
                l = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
                a = l < 128 ? Math.asin(l/128) : 0,
                z = l < 128 ? 255 - Math.cos(a) * 255 : 0,
                r = l < 128 ? 128 + (dx / 128) * (z / 255) * 128 : 0,
                g = l < 128 ? 128 + (dy / 128) * (z / 255) * 128 : 0,
                o = l >= 124 ? Math.max(0, 1 - (l-124)/4) : 1;

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+Math.floor(r)+','+Math.floor(g)+',0,'+o+')';
            ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
        }
    }

    barrel.setAttribute('xlink:href', canvas.toDataURL());

    var tx = 0,
        ty = 0;
    requestAnimationFrame(function updateAnimationFrame() {
        tx += 0.027;
        ty += 0.031;
        barrel.setAttribute('x', 128 + Math.sin(tx) * 120);
        barrel.setAttribute('y', 128 + Math.cos(ty) * 120);
        requestAnimationFrame(updateAnimationFrame);
    });
```

Formula is WAY too advanced for me to hack. 
So I was wondering is there any way I can generate these types of maps or maybe someone can help me with a formula.

Answer (score 1):

The displacement map could, at least roughly equivalent, be constructed as a SVG filter itself.

So you would think that you might be able to combine the drawing of the displacement map and its application to the image, in one SVG file. It turns out you can not, as browsers do not implement [`enable-background`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#AccessingBackgroundImage).

But, distributed among two files, it works. First, the displacement map:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1" height="300" width="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="barrel" x="-30%" y="-30%" width="160%" height="160%"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur result="result1" stdDeviation="10" />
      <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="5" result="result5"  />
      <feColorMatrix result="result3" type="matrix"
           values="0 0 0 -0.3 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 " />
      <feOffset result="result4" dy="-5" dx="5" />
      <feColorMatrix result="result2" in="result5" type="matrix"
           values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 " />
      <feOffset dy="5" dx="-5" />
      <feComposite result="result6" k3="1" k2="1" operator="arithmetic" in2="result4" />
    </filter>
    <clipPath id="cp" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="150" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle clip-path="url(#cp)" filter="url(#barrel)"
          cy="150" cx="150" r="100" />
</svg>
```

And secondly, the application to the image:

```
<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <filter id="barrel">
      <feImage id="filter-image" xlink:href="circle.svg" result="barrel"
               x="64" y="64" width="256" height="256" />
      <feDisplacementMap in2="barrel" in="SourceGraphic"
               xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="64" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="barrel"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://i.imgsafe.org/3353aef52f.jpg"
         x="0" y="0" height="512" width="512"/>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.imgsafe.org/3353aef52f.jpg"
         x="-16" y="-16" height="512" width="512" filter="url(#barrel)"/>
</svg>
```

I produced this with the Inkscape Filter editor, which gives a fair grafical interface for manipulating the filter components. You should probably experiment some more. Numbers to play around with probably are:

- `feGaussianBlur` blur radius - the width of the colored border, it would be my first candidate for what you call "sharpness"
- `feMorphology` erode radius should probably always be half the value of the blur radius
- `feOffset` dx/dy displace the red and green components relative to each other
- `feColorMatrix` Those number that are not zero could be variated. Look in the filter editor for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I almost created the filter I wanted, just curious how to add "volume" into this thing? I want effect similar to what CC Sphere in After Effects does. Now, thanks to you I figured out how to make effect sharper, but still couldn't figure out what is related to "volume".

Comment: The edit just now was because I found I had values towards the border inverted. I find that playing with the `feColorMatrix` values has the most pronunced effect on the "punch" of the whole thing.

Comment: Emulating a sphere will not work. The basic math is a Gauss curve.

Comment: Can you please update with a live working example?